# read xod file directly in iOS app using pdfTRON

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdftron

I have a requirement in my iOS app where in I am getting files in XOD format from the server. Now I want to view and annotate them directly in my app using pdftron without converting them to pdf. Is this possibe? And if yes, then how?

Comment: PDFTron has multiple solutions for document viewing on iOS. The two most popular are Webviewer (HTML5 SDK), and PDFNet (native SDK). Are you already using one of these? If not, do you have a preference?

Comment: I am using PDFNet

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PDFNet you can use [PTConvert FromXPS](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/docs/iOS/src/interface_p_t_convert.html#a3d85f884a20c88f466b81bedd311f0e2) method to convert the XOD to PDF, and then load the generated PDF into [PDFViewCtrl](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/docs/iOS/src/interface_p_t_p_d_f_view_ctrl.html).

The other option is to load a UIWebView into your application, and host [Universal WebViewer](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/index.html) there. Universal WebViewer will display the XOD file directly, with no need to convert, and includes full viewing experience, such as annotating.

Do you already have a license for PDFNet, or are you demoing still? If you have a license, it might not include XPS2PDF, needed for the call FromXPS. In this case you need to contact our sales department to get this addon.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I know about PTConvert FromXPS. But I wanted to know if there is some way that I can directly view and annotate xod file on my iOS device as the conversion can be time consuming and would occupy extra space as well. Currently I am using a demo version of PDFNet. But I am interested in the license as well. I am just verifying whether all my requirements can be met by pdfTron or not.